# Creating certificate causes HTTP request to fail

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a project currently which uses jose4j to check that the JWT provided to the API has the correct groups in Microsofts Azure AD. The AD keys are obtained by the following HTTP call:

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Response response = client.target(MICROSOFT_SERVICE_URL)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get();
```

The project then has to make a request to an external SOAP API. This is where the conflict is being caused. I've got the following code which sets the system properties required for the certificate:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "KeyStore.cert");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "KeyStore.cert");
```

When i make the request i get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

But when i comment out the keyStore and trustStore code it works.

Is there anything in the library that would be causing this conflict ?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Alex

Comment: `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "KeyStore.cert");` looks wrong.  That should be pointing to your `cacerts` file (which should contain all your certificates)  (or another keystore ".jks" file), rather than to an individual certificate file.

Comment: In your trust store you need the root certificate of the certificate sent by the server.

Comment: Thank you very much both of those solutions helped.